# Download software from OTN utilizing wget/curl

Tags: download

## How can I download Oracle Database Express Edition 11g utilizing wget/curl ?

Here is my link: http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/xe/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip

I am able to download from edelivery making use of the wget.sh script, but all files have a token at the end.

Java download works fine:

```
download java from oracle.com in one line!

wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jdk-8u112-linux-x64.rpm"
```

I have looked at some blogs, but they all seem outdated. Do I really have to fire up Firebug and troubleshoot this?

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, is because of the login needed to download at oracle's webpage. You are on the right direction... maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget